# PowerShell Sort-Object by formatted datetime

Tags: powershell

I want to list the times of certain Events in the System Event log for a specific day, e.g.

```
08:30       507
12:20       506
13:00       507
17:00       506
```

The problem I have is that I can't get the sorting to work. Here is my code and (example) results:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName 'System' | Where { $_.TimeGenerated -ge (Get-Date('06/12/2023')) -and $_.TimeGenerated -lt (Get-Date('07/12/2023')) -and (506, 507) -contains $_.InstanceId } | Select-Object { $_.TimeGenerated.ToString('hh:mm') }, InstanceId | Sort-Object @{ Expression = "TimeGenerated.ToString('hh:mm')"; Descending = $false }

 $_.TimeGenerated.ToString('hh:mm')  InstanceId
------------------------------------ ----------
13:00                                       507
17:00                                       506
08:30                                       507
12:20                                       506
12:20                                       506
```

I think the code is correct up to the last |, but the output is not in time order, and shows duplicates.
What I would like it the output in ascending time order, with no duplicates.
I'm using Powershell 5.1 and I don't care about the column headings and widths :-)

Thanks

Update:
The following gets the sorting right and removes duplicate entries where the hh:mm:ss is unique, but I need the hh:mm to be unique:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName 'System' | Where { $_.TimeGenerated -ge (Get-Date('06/12/2023')) -and $_.TimeGenerated -lt (Get-Date('07/12/2023')) -and (506, 507) -contains $_.InstanceId } | Select-Object TimeGenerated, InstanceId | Sort-Object -Property TimeGenerated -Unique
TimeGenerated       InstanceId
-------------       ----------
06/12/2023 13:00:12        507
06/12/2023 17:00:04        506
06/12/2023 08:30:38        507
06/12/2023 12:20:01        506
06/12/2023 12:20:28        506
```

Note: Including events 11 and 12 gives a bigger dataset for me

Comment: Instead of the formatted time string you should use a proper `[DateTime]` value. ‍♂️

Comment: @Olaf, please give an example

Comment: Aside - from a performance perspective, it would be better to store your reference dates in variables rather than calling e.g. ```Get-Date '06/12/2023'``` during every iteration of your ```where-object``` - probably doesn’t make *much* difference though unless you’ve got extremely a large dataset. Note also you don’t need the ```( … )``` around function parameters in Powershell  - ```Get-Date ‘06/12/2023’```is fine, and brackets do something subtly different by creating an *array* object which gets passed as a single parameter…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. You can create a label for a calculated/custom column. Then you can sort on that column.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName 'System' | 
Where { $_.TimeGenerated -ge (Get-Date('06/12/2023')) -and $_.TimeGenerated -lt (Get-Date('07/12/2023')) -and (506, 507) -contains $_.InstanceId } | 
Select-Object @{n="hh:mm"; e={$_.TimeGenerated.ToString('hh:mm')} }, InstanceId | 
Sort-Object "hh:mm" -Descending
```

Getting Unique items can generally be done by Select -Unique, but here it doesn't make much sense, as the events are all unique events in the Log.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I do need the -Unique on the end as the events lose the seconds information, but that works. You can see it better if you add events 11 and 12 to the list